# Why won't my image show in HTML?

Tags: html, image, directory

I'm having issues with getting an image to display on my HTML page. I currently have "image.png" in the same folder as the .html file and it still won't work. I am using Chrome btw. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <head>
        <title> Title </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1> This is an image </h1>
        <img src = “image.png” alt = “Image text”/>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Because you're using "smart" quotes in your attributes. Retype them in a plain text editor. `“` is not the same character as `"`

Comment: Note that you're also missing your opening `<html>` tag, which is an error but isn't part of the reason your image is not displaying.

Comment: Thank you, I disabled "smart" quotes in my settings and it worked. I also do have the opening <html> tag I just accidentally left it off while typing this question.

Comment: change  “ to "  or ' .. you might not be having image in the same directory

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using *smart quotes*. You need to use normal ones.

Replace `“` with '"' and `”` with `"`

```
<img src = "image.png" alt = "Image text"/>
```

You should use a Programming Editor like Notepad++ or Sublime Text, since they do not convert quotes into *smart quotes*

Also not that you are missing the opening `<html>` tag

Answer (score 0):

You should be using standard quotation marks, e.g. `" "`. So:

```
<img src = "image.png" alt = "Image text"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it in a folder inside the root folder?
Also use "".

```
<img src="image.png" alt="image text" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the editor you're using is applying some form of character encoding that's messing with your script, Notice how your quotation marks are slanted? What editor are you using?

The best way to fix this is to either put your code into Notepad (if you're on windows) and retype your quotation marks to remove the character encoding or configure your editor to use the correct encoding (Usually UTF-8)