# HTML Img tag for webpage

Tags: html, image

I am doing a project to enter a coding school and the requirements is to build a page and put a img on the page. I have been trying to upload a photo off of google and copy the url and put it under the src attribute and it isn’t working. No image has showed up and I tried about 4 or 5 times.

I use the img tag like this: `<img src=“url”>`.

If anyone knows what I am doing wrong can you help me?

Comment: Use straight quotes `""` instead of “smart quotes” `“”`.

Comment: please provide us the whole code of your project. Except the missing closing tag `<img {...} />` that looks good

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why won't my image show in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36012493/why-wont-my-image-show-in-html)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should consider constructing a [mre] to include in your Question. Your question is very straightforward, so you could probably insert all of the html code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

There actually could be a few reasons that your image isn't displaying!

I've listed **3 separate ways in which you can reference an image** so you can test them out on your code at school!

```html
<style>
 img {
  height: 100px;
 }
</style>
<div>
 In the same folder
 <br/>
 <img src="code.jpg"/>
<div>
<br/>
<div>
 In a sub folder
 <br/>
 <img src="./Folder/code.jpg"/>
<div>
<br/>
<div>
 From a URL
 <br/>
 <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1454165205744-3b78555e5572?auto=format&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&fit=crop&h=1000&q=80&w=1500"/>
<div>
```

Where your folder structure would look like this:

("code.jpg" is also in "Folder")

[image]